# Kontra.js | Collision Detection

Tags: javascript

I've tried several JS libraries now and always struggle with getting collision detection to work. It only seems to sometimes work and produces strange results!

The simplest example of this is the below Kontra.js example (codepen https://codepen.io/yellowsmiley/pen/oJzyrZ/). It creates several sprites and checks them all for collisions on each update of the gameloop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < sprites.length; j++) {
    let sprite1 = sprites[i];
    let sprite2 = sprites[j];
    if (isCollide(sprite1, sprite2)) {
      sprite1.color = "green";
      sprite2.color = "green";
    } else {
      sprite1.color = "red";
      sprite2.color = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

It's driving me mad and I can't seem to find anything online to help! Please help!

Comment: I was stumped for quite some time, but the issue is simple: you are constantly resetting the color to red for sprites that are colliding with others. Only the very last sprite stays green, because there's no negative test following the positive one. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/marjov?editors=0010

Comment: Btw, I also had to fix the for loops. With your code, all sprite collisions were checked twice, and sprites were checked against themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was stumped for quite some time, but the issue is simple: you are constantly resetting the color to red for sprites that are colliding with others. Only the very last sprite stays green, because there's no negative test following the positive one. codepen.io/anon/pen/marjov?editors=0010 – Chris G Dec 18 at 12:44

You beautiful genius Chris! Thank you!